# Loading data into Redshift via S3 COPY, multi-threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm doing some POC work with Redshift, loading data via S3 json files, using the copy command from a Java program.  This POC is testing an initial data migration that we'd do to seed Redshift, not daily use.  My data is split into about 7500 subfolders in S3, and I'd like to be able to insert the subfolders in parallel. Each subfolder contains about 250 json files, with about 3000 rows each to insert.

The single threaded version of my class loads files from one of my s3 subfolders in about 20 seconds (via a copy command).  However, when I introduce a second thread (each thread gets a redshift db connection from a BoneCP connection pool), each copy command, except for the 1st one, takes about 40 seconds.  When I run a query in Redshift to show all running queries, Redshift says that it's running two queries at the same time (as expected).  However, it's as if the 2nd query is really waiting for the 1st to complete before it starts work.  I expected that each copy command would still take only 20 seconds each.  The Redshift console shows that I only get up to 60% CPU usage running single or double threaded.

Could this be because I only have 1 node in my Redshift cluster?  Or is Redshift unable to open multiple connections to S3 to get the data?  I'd appreciate any tips for how to get some performance gains by running multi-threaded copy commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon Redshift loads data from Amazon S3 **in parallel, utilising all nodes**. From your test results, it would appear that running multiple `COPY` commands does not improve performance, since all nodes are already involved in the copy process.

For each table, always **load as many files as possible in a single `COPY` command**, rather than appending later. If you are loading multiple tables, it is likely best to do them sequentially (but your testing might find that loading multiple smaller tables can be done in parallel).

Some references:

- [Use a Single COPY Command to Load from Multiple Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-single-copy-command.html)
- [Using the COPY Command to Load from Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)
- [Quora: What are the ways to improve copy performance on Redshift?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-ways-to-improve-copy-performance-on-Redshift-Are-there-any-settings-configurations-at-the-cluster-level)

Comment: Also try to keep the size of the files as even as possible and if the files are small (KB ranges) don't bother to compress them.